# How do I compile "c++ functions from c" if c++ functions need other libraries?

Tags: c++, c

I have these files in the same folder:

function.h
function.cpp
main.c

If I have a simple function like `sum(int a){return a+a;}` (in function.cpp), I am able to compile it, but I need to use a library like this:

```
#include "something.hh"
void function(){
   ClassX* test;
   ...
}
```

The problem is that, when I'm trying to compile this, I get "undefined reference" in every class.

How should I compile this? 
Is this possible? I've read somewhere you can use a c++ function in c while its return type and its parameters are accessible from C. Is there any other requirement?

What I do:

```
g++ -c -I /folder/include  function.cpp -o function.o
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc main.o function.o -o exec
```

`In function.cpp undefined reference to ClassX`

Comment: Google "C++ name mangling" and insert `extern "C"` at the appropriate locations in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not   use of C and C++ but that   file containing entire ClassX is not compiled and hence in the third stage    in link time it gives error

```
gcc main.o function.o -o exec
```

Make sure that ClassX is defined in one .o file and that file is passed in above step.

Now coming to your question,
you can't compile C++ code is C compilers because C is not forward compatible but C++ is backward compatible to C that is to say that most of the C code will get compiled by C++ compiler with little change. But you can write a library in c or compile c code to .o and then use it in C++ compiler to do that you need to use extern "C" linkage.

```
extern "C"
{
....
}
```

Check this [link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)

Thanks

Comment: It's working now. You were right. I wasn't linking the static library. Newbie fail.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> How should i compile this? Is this possible?

Normally, there are two possibilities:

1. define your header file API in terms of functions only, declare those functions with `extern "C"` linkage and use them in C code.
2. if you have class declarations or other C++ specific code, compile your client code to C++ (i.e. move main.c to main.cpp).

In your case, you are trying to access a C++ class, in C code. **This is not possible.**

You can still use the functionality, but you will have to create an adaptation layer (with APIs declared as extern "C" and declaring no classes, templates or other C++ features).

Within this adaptation layer, classes or other C++ constructs can be hidden in structures opaque to client code.